# How to dynamically add filters to SQL to prepare data for UI

Tags: database, postgresql, user-interface

We have a UI where users are able to filter and order by specific columns. We currently pass the filtering or ordering options to the backend service, which manually modifies the relevant SQL query to add the filtering condition. While this has helped keep operations that are strongsuits of the database at the database layer, it has becoming a maintenance nightmare - as our queries grow larger in lines-of-code it becomes more challenging to edit the queries.

I have read of ORM's being an alternative to this, however their drawbacks are not acceptable for our usecase. I have also considered moving filtering out of the database and into application pods - while this increases compute, it would be easier to apply dynamic filtering rules at the application level using code. This allows us to cache a single query result that we can retrieve and filter as required. Furthermore, application pods are horizontally scalable so compute shouldn't be a major concern.

Which of the above options make most sense under a service-oriented architecture?